# "Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly" bug or what?

Tags: python

I've typed up this code but I can't see what's wrong with it.

```
if guess != number:
    number = str(number)
print('Nope. The number I was thinking of was ' + number)
```

It keeps giving me "Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly" even though I converted the integer into a string

Help out this noob please?

Comment: Oh, and by the way, it was copied directly from a book (don't worry, I studied it :P)

Comment: possible duplicate of [TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654168/typeerror-cant-convert-int-object-to-str-implicitly)

Comment: Put the `print` inside the `if` block

Comment: volatility, you should post that as the answer

Comment: You can shorten that to `if guess != number print('Nope. The number I was thinking of was ' + str(number))`.

Comment: Hint: did you consider the possibility that `guess` *is* equal to `number`? Should the `print` happen in this case? Does it? Why? (Hint: how does indentation work in Python?) (Voting to close as caused by a typo.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
>>> number='5'
>>> if raw_input('enter number:')!=number:
...    print('Nope. The number I was thinking of was {}'.format(number))
```

Or:

```
>>> number=5
>>> if int(raw_input('enter number:'))!=number:
...    print('Nope. The number I was thinking of was {}'.format(number))
```

With the [format method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) you will not need to do explicit type conversion to print it since you are not concatenating two strings. You will need to make sure that you are comparing a string to a string or an int to an int in the if statement though.

(If you are using Python 3, `raw_input` is [input](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#input) for the same functionality...)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to put your `print` inside the `if` block.

```
if guess != number:
    number = str(number)
    print('Nope. The number I was thinking of was ' + number)
```

In your original code, it printed even if you guessed right, which meant that the `if` block didn't execute and so `number` was still an integer.

You could also use string formatting to avoid having to convert `number` into the string.

```
print('Nope. The number I was thinking of was %d' % number)
```

[drewk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15013455/1907098) has mentioned the newer string formatting method.