# Getting a TypeError: Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly?

Tags: python

this is part of my GCSE computing code project and i cant get it to work properly please help me.
it is meant to be a 'Encounter' game between two characters

```
import random

tryagain = "Y" or "y"


char1name = input(str("character 1 please enter your name "))
char2name = input(str("character 2 please enter your name "))

print ("Player 1, your name is " + char1name)
print ("Player 2, your name is " + char2name)
print ("  ")
player1skill = input(str("what is your skill level " + char1name + "? "))
player2skill = input(str("what is your skill level " + char2name + "? "))
player1strength = input(str("what is your strength level " + char1name + "? "))
player2strength = input(str("what is your strength level " + char2name + "? "))

print (char1name + " has a skill of " + player1skill + " and a strength of " +  player1strength)
print (char2name + " has a skill of " + player2skill + " and a strength of " +  player2strength)

if (int(player1strength) >= int(player2strength)):
    strength_modifier = ((int(player1strength)) - (int(player2strength)))
else:
    strength_modifier = (int(player2strength) - (int(player1strength)))

if (int(player1skill) >= int(player2skill)):
    skill_modifier = ((int(player1skill)) - (int(player2skill)))
else:
    skill_modifier = (int(player2skill) - (int(player1skill)))
print("The strength modifier is " + (int(strength_modifier) / (int(5))))
print("The skill modifier is " + (int(skill_modifier) // (int(5))))

roll_player1 = random.randint(1,6)
roll_player2 = random.randint(1,6)

if int(roll_player1) == int(roll_player2):
    print("no changes are made")
else: print(char1name +"'s skill has gone up to " + (str(player1skill) +  str(skill_modifier)))
print("and their strength has gone up to" + (int(player1strength) + int(strength_modifier)))
if int(roll_player1) <= int(roll_player2):
    print(char2name + "'s skill has gone up to " + (int(player2skill) +  int(skill_modifier)))
    print("and their strength has gone up to" + (int(player2strength) +       int(strength_modifier)))
```

this is the error i keep getting, what is the problem??

```
character 1 please enter your name player1
character 2 please enter your name player2
Player 1, your name is player1
Player 2, your name is player2

what is your skill level player1? 10
what is your skill level player2? 5
what is your strength level player1? 20
what is your strength level player2? 10
player1 has a skill of 10 and a strength of 20
player2 has a skill of 5 and a strength of 10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\fileserver-01\studenthome$\*serverlocation*
 line 29, in <module>
    print("The strength modifier is " + (int(strength_modifier) / (int(5))))
TypeError: Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly
```

Comment: Already answered - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654168/typeerror-cant-convert-int-object-to-str-implicitly?rq=1

Comment: There are many problems in this code. For example, `tryagain = "Y" or "y"` does not do what is presumably intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of this operation:

```
(int(strength_modifier) / (int(5)))
```

Is a float. To change it into a string, just convert it to string.

```
str(int(strength_modifier) / (int(5)))
```

Comment: The division of two `int` returns a `float`?

Comment: @Cyber in Python3 it does

Comment: @Cyber Yeah, apparently so. Python 3.

Comment: Hmm didn't know that, was that to fix the rounding/truncation surprise?

Comment: The ground work for this was laid long ago; Python 2.2 introduced the `//` operator to perform true integer division, freeing `/` to be (eventually) reassigned to always perform floating-point division.