# Error "Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly"

Tags: python, string, typeerror

I just started [Automate The Boring Stuff](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/), I'm at chapter 1.

```
myname = input()
print ('It is nice to meet you,' + myname)
lengthofname = len(myname)
print ('your name is this many letters:' + lengthofname)
```

I ran this, it gave me `Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly`.
My reasoning at line 3 is that I want the variable `myname` to be converted into an integer and then plugged into line 4.

Why would this be an erroneous way of coding?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654168/typeerror-cant-convert-int-object-to-str-implicitly. Please google before you post.

Comment: Use comma to seperate arguments in `print()` and `print()` will convert them to string automatically - `print ('your name is this many letters:', lengthofname)`

Answer (score 4):

When you have `print ('your name is this many letters:' + lengthofname)`, python is trying to add an integer to a string (which of course is impossible).

There are 3 ways to resolve this problem.

1. `print ('your name is this many letters:' + str(lengthofname))`
2. `print ('your name is this many letters: ', lengthofname)`
3. `print ('your name is this many letters: {}'.format(lengthofname))`

Answer (score 2):

You have problem because `+` can add two numbers or concatenate two strings - and you have `string + number` so you have to convert number to string before you can concatenate two strings - `string + str(number)`

```
print('your name is this many letters:' + str(lengthofname))
```

But you can run `print()` with many arguments separated with comma - like in other functions - and then Python will automatically convert them to string before `print()` displays them.

```
print('your name is this many letters:', lengthofname)
```

You have only remeber that `print` will add space between arguments.
(you could say "comma adds space" but print does it.)

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be Python 3.x. The following is the corrected code; just convert the `lengthofname` to string during `print`.

```
myname = input()
print ('It is nice to meet you,' + myname)
lengthofname = len(myname)
print ('your name is this many letters:' + str(lengthofname))
```