# "TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly" When trying to print a int in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a beginner to python and I'm trying to make a text adventure game in python as a filler of time. I'm having a problem with one of my lines of code that I don't know how to fix. I'm getting the error:

```
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

and I don't know how to fix it. It's for a health counter I have got in the game that degrades health if you get hit. This is the code of my game so far:

```
# Imports
import sys
import os

# Main Vars
gmName = "TXT Adventure"
gmFileName = "txtAdventure"
gmVersion = "2.5.0"
gmSplit = "--------"

# Player Vars
plHealth = 100
plHealthO = 100 # Original Health
plName = "N/A"

# Character Vars
ch1 = "Tom"
ch2 = "Josh"
ch3 = "Demitrie"

# Enemy Vars - en<num>H = heath of enemy
en1 = "Sand Viper"
en1H = "5"
en2 = "Water Venom Moth"
en2H = "7"
en3 = "Giant Ant"
en3H = "10"

# Game
print("Finished Loading!")
print(gmSplit)
cont = input("Press Enter To Continue..")
print(gmSplit)
print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n") # Space from loading screen
print("Welcome to " + gmName + "!")
print("You are playing on version: " + gmVersion)
print(gmSplit)
plName = input("Who are you, son?\n--> ")
if plName == "":
    exit = input("Invalid Name, Press enter to restart.. ")
    os.startfile(gmName + '.py')
    sys.exit(0)
if plName == " ":
    exit = input("Invalid Name, Press enter to restart.. ")
    os.startfile(gmName + '.py')
    sys.exit(0)
cont = input("Press Enter to continue, " + plName + "!")
print(gmSplit)
print(ch1 + ": Well hello, " + plName + ". Nice to see you!")
cont = input("Press Enter to continue, " + plName + "!")
print(gmSplit)
option = input("What do you want to do?\n1 = Play\n2 = Exit\n--> ")
if option == "1":
    cont = input("Press Enter to continue, " + plName + "!")
    print(gmSplit)
    plAge = input("What is your age, " + plName + "?" + "\n--> ")
    print(gmSplit)
    option2 = input("So you are " + plName + " and you are " + plAge + " years old?\n1 = True\n2 = False\n--> ")
    if option2 == "1":

        # Start of the game
        print(gmSplit)
        print("Well welcome to " + gmName + ", " + plName + "!")
        print(gmSplit)
        start = input("Press Enter To Start The Game..")
        print(gmSplit)
        print(ch1 + ": Hi there traveler, we are from far away lands!")
        cont = input("Press Enter To Continue..")
        print(gmSplit)
        print(ch2 + ": Like the scally said, we' came from a long way away ay!")
        cont = input("Press Enter To Continue..")
        print(gmSplit)
        print(ch1 + " + " + ch2 + ": I WILL KILL UUU!")
        cont = input("Press Enter To Continue..")
        print(gmSplit)
        option = input(ch3 + ": Break it up you to! Don't you think, " + plName + "!\n1 = True\n2 = False\n--> ")
        if option == "1":
            print(ch3 + ": Well thank you, " + plName + ".")
            print(ch1 + " + " + ch2 + ": Ugh...")
            print(gmSplit)
        else:
            print(ch3 + ": Oh, i'm sorry, did I upset you..")
            cont = input("Press Enter To Continue..")
            print(gmSplit)
        print(ch3 + ": Well anyway, they are still fighting..")
        print(ch1 + " + " + ch2 + ": ARAGHHH!")
        print(gmSplit)
        cont = input("Press Enter To Continue..")
        print(gmSplit)
        print(ch1 + " + " + ch2 + " + " + ch3 + ": Okay lets start the adventure!")
        cont = input("Press Enter To Continue..")
        way = input(ch1 + ": Okay, " + plName + ". What way are we going?\n1 = North\n2 = South\n--> ")
        if way == "1":
            print(ch1 + ": Okay, lets go north!")
        elif way == "2":
            print(ch1 + ": Okay, lets go south!")
            print(gmSplit)
            cont = input("Press Enter To Continue..")
            print(gmSplit)
            print(ch3 + ": But I dont like going south, it's scary that way..")
            print(gmSplit)
            cont = input("Press Enter To Continue..")
            print(gmSplit)
            print(ch1 + " + " + ch2 + ": Shut up, " + ch3 + "!")
            print(ch3 + ": Please don't go this way, " + plName + " :(")
            option = input("1 = Continue South\n2 = Go North insted\n--> ")
            if option == "1":
                plHealth -= 5
                print(gmSplit)
                print(ch3 + ": Why, " + plName + ". Why did you do this!")
                print(gmSplit)
                print("*" + ch3 + " slaps you, your health goes from " + plHealthO + " to: " + plHealth + "!")
        else:
            print("You picked an invalid choice!")
            exit = input("Press enter to re-do choice!")
        print(gmSplit)
        print("You have encounterd a wild: " + en1 + "! It has " + en1H + " health!")
        option = input("What do you want to do?\n1 = Attack\n2 = Run\n--> ")
        if option == "1":
            en1H = "3"
            plHealth -= 2
            print("The " + en1 + "'s health has gone down to: " + en1H + "!")
            cont = input("Press Enter To Continue..")
            print(gmSplit)
            print("The " + en1 + " attacked you!")
            cont = input("Press Enter To Continue..")
            print(gmSplit)
            print("Your health was: " + plHealthO + "But now it has gone down to: " + plHealth + "!")
            cont = input("Press Enter To Continue..")
            print(gmSplit)
            print(ch1 + " + " + ch2 + " Helped  you and killed the beast!")
            cont = input("Press Enter To Continue..")
            print(gmSplit)
            print("Okay, where do you want to go now?")
            option = input("1 = Keep Heading Forward\n2 = Camp for the night\n--> ")
        elif option == "2":
            exit = input(en1)
        else:
            print("You chose an invalid choice!")
            print(gmSplit)
            restart = input("Press enter to restart..")
            os.startfile(gmFileName + '.py')
            sys.exit(0)
    elif option2 == "2":
        exit = input("Press enter to restart.. ")
        os.startfile(gmFileName + '.py')
        sys.exit(0)
    else:
        exit = input("Press enter to restart.. ")
        os.startfile(gmFileName + '.py')
        sys.exit(0)
elif option == "2":
        exit = input("Press enter to exit " + gmName + ".. ")
        os.startfile(gmFileName + '.py')
        sys.exit(0)
else:
        exit = input("Press enter to restart.. ")
        os.startfile(gmFileName + '.py')
        sys.exit(0)
```

The full error with my game goes like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\Phyton Programming\txtAdventure.py", line 112, in <module>
    print("*" + ch3 + " slaps you, your health goes from " + plHealthO + " to: " + plHealth + "!")
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

I hope you can help me and sorry if i'm just not seeing something very obvious. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654168/typeerror-cant-convert-int-object-to-str-implicitly)

Comment: You should include only the relevant code regarding the error. The full error message says it's on line 112. You should include just that line and the relevant surrounding lines, it make it so much easier for people to answer you questions because they don't have to search for the error source themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`plHealthO` and `plHealth` are `int`s. To join them with a string you have to implicitly convert them to a strings.

```
print("*" + ch3 + " slaps you, your health goes from " + str(plHealthO) + " to: " + str(plHealth) + "!")
```

Comment: Would that still work with a health counter, going something like "plHealth = plHealth -= 1". Thanks!

Comment: That works with any integer variable. Although your example statement is wrong, should be `plHealth -= 1` only. Hope this answers your question :)

Answer (score 0):

to convert int to string use use `print ("text"+str(variable_name))`