# Keep getting this error not sure why "Can't convert 'set' object to str implicitly"

Tags: python, django, django-sessions

```
@admin.register(Book)
class BookAdmin(ImportExportActionModelAdmin):
   resource_class = BookResource

   def get_import_form(self):
       return CustomImportForm

   def get_resource_kwargs(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       rk = super().get_resource_kwargs(request, *args, **kwargs)

       rk['input_author'] = None

       if request.POST:
           author = request.POST.get('input_author', None)
           if author:
               request.session['input_author'] = author
           else:
               try:
                   author = request.session['input_author']
               except KeyError as e:
                   raise Exception("Context failure on row import" + {e})

           rk['input_author'] = author
       return rk
```

Have this code in django admin page, but getting an error during the export. Can anyone let me know where is the issue?

[image]

Comment: Somebody had a similar error in the past. The advice was you must do "str(xxxxCodeTheUserHad)" Link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654168/typeerror-cant-convert-int-object-to-str-implicitly

Comment: I saw that, but is there a way to somehow by pass it? Say if you it is set then ignore it?

Comment: @bisamov can you post the entire traceback (and as text ideally).

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is on this line:

```
raise Exception("Context failure on row import" + {e})
```

The ‘{e}’ means that you create a set containing the error, and try to join it to the exception message string. You should be able to get rid of that error by replacing ‘{e}’ with just ‘e’.